# What is the Flux State?

Tags: shadowrun

In the 2050s era of *Shadowrun*, Berlin is under something called the "Flux State". What exactly is this?

The video game *Shadowrun Returns: Dragonfall* features it prominently and refers to it as an "anarchist experiment" or something. However, there is apparently something more to it, since one character contrasts it with a lawless region saying that it's "anarchy, but without the stability of the Flux State".

What exactly is the Flux State? What is its relationship to anarchy and how does it provide a stable society?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Berlin seceded from Germany after the anarchist revolution of 2039, creating the so called "Flux State."

2) The Flux State's relation to anarchy is it was created by the "anarchist movement Berlin" when the group took power following the successful anarchist revolution.

3) The Flux State could hardly be called a "stable society" except when compared to other lawless areas of the Shadowrun world. Power shifts constantly and the vacuum left by government is filled by other powerful entities. If the oxymoron of an "anarchist civilization" were to exist, it would have crumbling infrastructure and be survival of the fittest/wealthiest (as seen in game).

The Arcade SE has a bit on the topic [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270484/what-is-the-flux-state).